# Send different email template to customer

Tags: magento2, php, module, email-templates

I have a custom module which is a custom form for the user to book an appointment, this form works fine with no issues, the form once submitted sends and email to both the admin and user/customer but it uses the same template. What I'd like is the customer to receive a different email with a success message etc.

I have this is my email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
 
    <template id="video-appointment" label="Video Appointment Form" file="video-appointment.html" type="html" module="VideoAppointment_Appointmentform" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="video-appointment-customer" label="Video Appointment Success" file="video-appointment-customer.html" type="html" module="VideoAppointment_Appointmentform" area="frontend"/>
     
</config>
```

And I have this in my Post.php file

```
public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try
        {
            // Send Mail
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
             
            $sender = [
                'name' => $post['name'],
                'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
                'email' => $post['email'],
                'phone' => $post['phone'],
                'byphone' => $post['byphone'],
                'bytext' => $post['bytext'],
                'byemail' => $post['byemail']
            ];
             
            $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_custom1/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
             
            $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_custom1/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
             
             
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('video-appointment')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name'  => $post['name'],
                    'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
                    'email'  => $post['email'],
                    'phone'  => $post['phone'],
                    'byphone' => $post['byphone'],
                    'bytext' => $post['bytext'],
                    'byemail' => $post['byemail']
                ])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                ->addBcc($post['email'])
                //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')
                ->getTransport();
                 
                $transport->sendMessage();
                 
                $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Thankyou for your appointment booking request, we will be in contact with you shortly.');
                $this->_redirect('video-appointment/index/index');
                 
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
```

I can see the email template is being set by

```
->setTemplateIdentifier('video-appointment')
```

But how do I set another template (ie the `video-appointment-customer.html`) to send to the customer?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to send a completely different email then create one more email template as you did for the customer to admin.
2. If you want to change Dear  to Dear  then Pass var to the email template accordingly.
3. Use try to use call .phtml file in template and then set condition accordingly.